# Mongodb tailable cursor, high cpu usage - nodejs + mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi I have been trying to use mongodb tailable cursor to get live data on my graph, so far it's all good with some minor issues.. one of the main issue is related to high cpu usage, on my first call with following option set for mongo tailable query

```
tailable: true,
awaitdata: true,
numberOfRetries: -1
```

the cpu usage almost 8-10% and after that for each additional request it increase with same amount of load...

however when  I change it to

```
tailable: true,
awaitdata: false,
numberOfRetries: -1,
tailableRetryInterval: 200
```

the cpu usage goes down and it's all good

**awaitdata** {Boolean}, awaitdata allow the cursor to wait for data, only applicable for tailable cursor.

**tailableRetryInterval** {Number}, tailableRetryInterval specify the miliseconds between getMores on tailable cursor.

my question is, is it better to turn off the awaitdata and use tailableRetryInterval which is going easy on cpu or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

1. A CPU usage of 10% is nothing. Really. Used resources are good resources since *they are actually used for something more useful than idling around*. Until a certain threshold, of course.
2. When you reduce the interval in which the tailable cursor is checked, as you did, of course the CPU is used less. It really depends on how your use case looks like. If you can live with the fact that there is a certain delay until an entry is processed, that's fine. But usually, you want things to be processed as fast as possible. Also keep in mind that multiple entries may have entered the capped collection when you wait for a certain while - and their processing might need time and CPU cycles. I tend to try to keep CPU load as even as possible and prevent spikes at all cost. Because when spikes caused by different reasons happen the same time, you are in trouble.
3. Hard to say if you do something wrong unless we know your functional and non-functional requirements, constraints, use case or a single line of code.